# "npm start" doesn't run on local host

Tags: angular, npm, npm-start

this is what i get any time i input the command `npm start`. i don't know where this error is coming from as i am totally new to angular. I have not tried any thing as i am completely new to angular. Bellow is the error message i got. Kindly help.

```
$ npm start
```

And I get this result:

```
> ng-fundamentals@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Lenovo\ng-fundamentals> ng serve
npm ERR! file ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
npm ERR! path ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
npm ERR! ng-fundamentals@0.0.0 start: `ng serve`
npm ERR! spawn ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\ ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ng-fundamentals@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-14T20_51_21_756Z-debug.log
```

Comment: 1. How did you create the application ? (using the CLI ?) 2. Do you have a node_module folder ? 3. Can you give the result of `ng --version` ?

Comment: 1. yes i used the cli
2. i have it. 
3. this is what the command gives when  run it:

bash: ng: command not found